# My generated rig doesn't match my meta rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm fairly new and I used rigify to set up a meta rig but when I use generate rig, a standard rig that doesn't match my meta rig at all appears.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: can you add screenshots or a sample blend using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: I actually figured it out, it was because my scale was not applied.  I guess Rigify needs all scales involved to be 1,1,1